# Java library for object avoid and ortogonal routing

Tags: java, layout, orthogonal

I'm searching for a free library that allows me to add geometric objects and create connections between them using orthogonal/polyline layout. I don't need to display them, just to calculate the orthogonal routing points for each connection with the minimum crossings and path sharing, like in this example from yWorks:

http://docs.yworks.com/yfiles/doc/developers-guide/figures/grid.gif

I already tested libavoid and its great but till now I can't achieve a result as in the above example. Any more suggestions?

Many thanks,

Vitor.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/) library. It's ditributed under BSD license and includes orthogonal layout since 1.6.1 version